# netty: why write() must get executed in Eventloop thread assigned to the channel?

Tags: multithreading, netty

It's common that the app exchanges data between channels.

For example, for proxy server, each inbound connection would be associated with an outbound connection and data exchanged between them. In this case, I know I could construct a client `BootStrap` and do `b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop());`. Then both channels could be handled in the same thread.

But what about data exchange between inbound channels? The chat room is the typical case. The coupling is arbitrary, for two channels which happens to have different `EventLoop` thread, they would pay unnecessary context switch overhead.

So I am just confused that why such rule exists? Could we just write data to the `Channel` socket (maybe with lock hold) if the write could be done non-blocking (the OS socket buffer has free space or the peer consuming fast) in any calling thread, and if it would blocks, we could then trigger the `EventLoop` thread to register write bit to the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a design choice that was done in Netty which also simplifies the writing of custom `ChannelHandler`s. By always dispatch to the `EventLoop` inbound and outbound handler have the same semantics when it comes to executing these and so the user basically can write its handlers as "single-threaded".

As this is in the "core" of netty there is no way to change this.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand the benefit of the unified handling in the same I/O thread. But how to exchange data between inbound channels (which could be coupled arbitrarily, so re-register them to same thread is meaningless) without the context switch overhead (assuming these two channels happens to be assigned to different I/O thread)? Is it a corner case?

Comment: There is now way to do this without context switch if these are on different EventLoops. Either pin them to the same EventLoop or you will need to "pay" for it.

Comment: Yes, re-register channels to same thread would work for fixed relationship. But as said, the coupling between inbound channels may be arbitrary, and maybe one channel would be coupled with many other channels (many-to-many), you cannot put tons of channels into one thread, right?

Comment: It all depends on what you do in your ChannelHandlers. As everything is non-blocking by default its not unusually to have thousands (or even 10th of thousands of Channels per EventLoop.